# How to count the amount of space delimiters in a string using the for loop?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, keyboard, token

I am new to Java and am working on an assignment where you need to count the amount of delimiters or spaces in a string that the user inputs.

I have to use a method that prompts the user to input a string using the Keyboard class. However, I am using BlueJ and Keyboard is not compatible with the BlueJ library thing. I do know that Scanner could be as an alternative with Keyboard but I am not sure how to read a string using Scanner.

Furthermore, I am not sure how I am suppose to structure my for loop to count the delimiters in a string. I am sorry for my high misunderstanding with this and I know that I am asking a lot but please don't feel obligated to answer everything, just whatever you want to or what you can easily answer. Here is my code below:

```
import cs1.keyboard;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Counting_Chars
{
   public static void main (String []args)
   {
      int spaceCount = 0, characterCount = 0;
      String line, word;
      StringTokenizer tokenizer;

      System.out.println("Please enter text (type DONE to quit):");    
      line = scan.nextLine();
      String phrase = line;

      for (String ch = phrase.charAt(line);; ch <= line; count++)// I don't really know what I am doing here
      {
         System.out.println (count);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are having multiple issues here. Perhaps it would be good to break the problem down into smaller parts and build your way back up again.

I would suggest something like:

1. write a program that just prints out some text (like 'Hello World')
2. write a program that asks the user to type in a line of text and
   then just prints out that exact same text again
3. then worry about counting the spaces in the string